# AWK Randomly choose 1 of 2 actions when condition is met

Tags: bash, awk

I can substitute a value with another one in a file when my condition is met with this:

```
awk '{if (length($4)*2+1 != length($5) && $10 ~ /^1\/2/) sub("1/2","1/1"); print}' MyFile
```

Which replaces "1/2" with "1/1" in lines where my 2 conditions are true.

There are several such cases in my files, and what I would really like to do is to replace "1/2" with "1/1" in roughly half of the cases, while replace "1/2" with "2/2" in roughly the other half of the cases. That is, randomly choose one of the 2 possible actions `sub("1/2","1/1")` or `sub("1/2","2/2")`. Is this possible in any way?

Many thanks!

Comment: `if(rand()>0.5)` maybe?

Comment: Be careful with this `$10 ~ /^1\/2/` -- that will match if $10 == "1/23456" -- do you want to use `$10 == "1/2"` instead (which is easier to read)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with calling rand() for every line is you could end up with all of the sub()s being the same as each other. To guarantee roughly half and half you could do:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { srand() }
    length($4)*2+1 != length($5) && $10 ~ /^1\/2/ {
        if ( ++cnt % 2 ) {
            dir = (rand() < 0.5 ? 1 : 0)
        }
        else {
            dir = !dir
        }
        sub("1/2", (dir ? "1/1" : "2/2"))
    }
    { print }
' MyFile
```

but it's a bit less random since every 2nd line is the opposite of the previous one.

Comment: Thank you Ed! You are right! One little thing: my awk knowledge was enough for modifying the other code, but this one is a little bit more complicated to let it print the lines as they are when conditions are not met(which my code in question was doing even though I didn't explain it clearly); any chance upgrading it in that way, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '
    length($4)*2+1 != length($5) && $10 ~ /^1\/2/ {
        sub("1/2", rand() < 0.5 ? "1/1" : "2/2")
        print
    }
' MyFile
```

Comment: Adding `BEGIN{srand()}` might be useful. It'd be necessary if you wanted different output each time you run the script on the same input file.

Comment: Thanks! This was printing lines only when the conditions are met (my question wasn't clear with it sorry). In case someone else wants it in that way too, here is the version that also prints the other lines in the file as they are: `awk '{if (length($4)*2+1 != length($5) && $10 ~ /^1\/2/) sub("1/2", rand() < 0.5 ? "1/1" : "2/2"); print}' MyFile`

Answer (score 1):

here is another way with dynamically adjusting the threshold to produce a more balanced distribution.

```
awk 'BEGIN {srand()}
     length($4)*2+1 != length($5) && $10 ~ /^1\/2/ {
          r=rand()<(1-(c1+1)/(c+2)); 
          c1+=r; c++;
          sub("1/2", r?"1/1":"2/2")}1' file
```

assume by chance first 3 r values are 1, the fourth one will be more likely to be 0 (prob of 1 will be 1-4/5=0.2 instead of 0.5).  This still doesn't give you exact half and half split.  For that, easier to have the exact count up front and use `shuf`.

Perhaps also restrict the `sub` to `$10` only?